# ReSharper Possible Null Exception when null is already checked

Tags: c#, resharper, extension-methods, nullreferenceexception, code-contracts

This is ReSharper 7 with Visual Studio 2012. With the sample below

```cs
// This code works fine and as expected and ReShrper is happy with it
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extension) && extension.Length == 3)
{
    // do something
}

// ReSharper highlights "extension" in extension.Length with "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'"
if (!extension.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && extension.Length == 3)
{
    // do something
}
```

And, I have created the following extension method:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string s)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
    }
}
```

I looked at the reflected code of `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and it doesn't have any related code or attribute that would highlight to R# that the check is verified. Is this hardcoded in R#?

I looked at Code Contracts, but I am not sure it would help in my case.

Do you have a workaround for proving to ReSharper that the check condition is already verified by my extension method?

Comment: Slightly confused - are you using .NET 4 or not?

Comment: If you add a C# tag your code will be C#-highlighted.

Comment: @AakashM It is .NET 4, thersch done!

Comment: @Adam I've updated my answer for Resharper 7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Available in Resharper 7 and above

```
[ContractAnnotation("null=>true")]
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string s)
```

Your project isn't going to know what `ContractAnnotation` is. You need to add it to your project. The preferred method is via nuget:

> PM> Install-Package [JetBrains.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations)

Alternatively you can directly embed the source into your project:

> Resharper -> Options -> Code Annotations -> Copy default implementation to clipboard

Then paste that into a new file, eg Annotations.cs. The `ContractAnnotation` definition lives in that file. For an official article on ContractAnnotation see [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/)

---

### Previous answer (for non R#7 versions)

> Is this hardcoded in R#?

No, Resharper uses External Annotations to provide this functionality. [This article](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/11/resharper-nullreferenceexception-analysis-and-its-contracts/) should answer all your questions, including a solution to provide your own external annotation for your `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method.

#### Example

*note: external annotations appear to only work on referenced libraries; if your reference is from a project the external annotations are not picked up; this is less than ideal*

Suppose you have your extension method in a class called `TempExtensions` which itself resides in an assembly named `ClassLibrary1`

You need to add a new file at this location

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.0\Bin\ExternalAnnotations.NETFramework.ExternalAnnotations\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.xml

The contents of the xml should contain:

```
<assembly name="ClassLibrary1">
  <member name="M:ClassLibrary1.TempExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.String)">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String,System.Boolean)">
        <argument>null=&gt;true</argument>
        <argument>true</argument>
    </attribute>
  </member>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works! Also, thank you for giving a solution for the specific example that I gave.

Comment: Related, additional annotations documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know is this a problem of the resharper. It can not look into methods and verify that in the method the null-check will be done. If u want to avoid this message i think u have to do the null-checking yourself. But i would prefer to ignore the resharper-message in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I see is by adding function parameter to extension method.

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static bool IsNotNullAndNotWhiteSpaceAnd(this string s, Func<string, bool> func)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
      return false;
    }

    return func(s);
  }
}
```

Example for using this extension method:

```cs
string extension = null;     //Test for null
//string extension = "123";  //Test for Length==3


if (extension.IsNotNullAndNotWhiteSpaceAnd(_ => _.Length == 3))
{
  Console.Out.WriteLine("Length == 3");
}
else
{
  Console.Out.WriteLine("Null or WhiteSpace or Length != 3");
}
```

Comment: My concern is not the length check, that was an example. My concern is having ReSharper notified that I have done the null check in this function.